# How to access JSON Array elements returned from an AJAX response

Tags: javascript, json

how to access JSON array elements for the following JSON Code? further how do i calculate the size of the returned object array?

```
[
{
lastInvAmt: 0
bwHrs: 0
nbwHrs: 0
unbilledAmt: 0
unbilledHrs: 0
dbID: 0`
},{
lastInvAmt: 0
bwHrs: 0
nbwHrs: 0
unbilledAmt: 0
unbilledHrs: 0
dbID: 0`
}]
```

Comment: This is not a valid JSON string; in JSON, every string, whether it represents a key or a value, should be encapsulated in double quotes (`"`). Also notice the strange backticks after the `dbID` values. You can test your string with http://www.jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks i will check that out.I was also thinking the same

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you assign it to variable? Or I don't understand anything? :)

**edited to work with json string**

```
var ar = eval('[
{
lastInvAmt: 0
bwHrs: 0
nbwHrs: 0
unbilledAmt: 0
unbilledHrs: 0
dbID: 0
},{
lastInvAmt: 0
bwHrs: 0
nbwHrs: 0
unbilledAmt: 0
unbilledHrs: 0
dbID: 0
}]');
```

Why do you have single quote  dbID: 0`. Is it spelling error?

Comment: The OP probably gets above thingadongdong as a string in JSON, which he wants to be converted to a real object (or array, in this case).

Comment: then it is required to use eval of course. I will edit my code.

Comment: No, it is not required and *could* even be dangerous (malicious code injection). Use a JSON parser instead.